# Convert tab delimiter to semicolon

Tags: csv, powershell

I have updated a piece of software for our T&A system, this produces a CSV file in tab-delimited format. The payroll software needs this in the older format which was semicolon-delimited. I have been in touch with both vendors and neither one has a way to accommodate the other so I need to convert the CSV file to suit the payroll software. I have tried to do this with PowerShell with mixed results.

First I tried

```
Import-Csv ".\desktop\new version.csv" -Delimiter `t |
  Export-Csv ".\converted.csv" -NoTypeInf
```

which removed the tab delimiter but didn't do the `;`. So I then tried

```
Import-Csv ".\desktop\new version.csv" -Delimiter `t |
  Export-Csv ".\desktop\converted.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ";"
```

which did convert it from tabbed to `;`, but only for the headers. It totally ignored the rest of the data. I then tried a different approach and used

```
$path = ".\desktop\new.csv"
$outPath = ".\desktop\converted.csv"
Get-Content -path $path |
  ForEach-Object {$_ -replace "`t",";" } |
  Out-File -filepath $outPath
```

which formatted the file correctly, but put an extra empty row between each row of data. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong!

Comment: Your second command should have worked just fine unless your input TSV is malformed.

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure you are having an encoding issue with your last example. `Get-Content` reads in as Ascii whereas `Out-File` defaults to Unicode. Either set the `-Encoding` on `Out-File` or just use `Set-Content`.

```
Get-Content -path $path |
ForEach-Object {$_ -replace "`t",";" } |
Set-Content -filepath $outPath
```

You could even trim this down a bit if need be.

```
(Get-Content -path $path) -replace "`t",";" | Set-Content -filepath $outPath
```

However your 2nd code example...

> ```
> Import-Csv ".\desktop\new version.csv" -Delimiter `t | Export-Csv ".\desktop\converted.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ";"
> ```

should have worked just fine to replacing the tabs to semicolons. If it is not working then I would think your source data has an issue.

---

**About the source file**

Based on comments the code above is creating a trailing column. Most likely reason for that is trailing tabs on each row that are being converted. If that is the case then a little more manipulation would be required. Easier to use the `foreach` loop in this case.

```
Get-Content -path $path |
ForEach-Object {$_.Trim() -replace "`t",";" } |
Set-Content -filepath $outPath
```

That would remove the last tab/whitespace of each line. There is a potential ***enormous caveat*** doing it this way though. I think it has the potential to drop data if you have empty columns on the end. However if those columns were already empty it should not matter as long as the header is formed well and the input program can account for this. Else you are looking at reading in the file with `Import-CSV` and dropping the last column which can be done.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the suggestions, I've tired those and they do work but again add an extra row of blank data so i'm guessing the original csv file has some formatting/data issues.

Comment: @SimonH So is there a trailing tab in your source data?

Comment: There must be but I can't work out where! the software that produces the csv is not the best so it's very possible that there is a bug in the way it creates the file.

Comment: thanks for the assistance. I think the data I'm getting is totally screwed up. If I open the original csv file I have it formats correctly but if I look at the details in the preview pane if Explorer I can see the following "U S E R  I D  U S E R  N A M E" so it's putting a space between each character and 2 between each word which I don't think is helping matters! Think i'm going to have to go to the vendor of the T&A system and see if I can get any assistance from them.

Comment: That is an encoding issue so you need to know how the file is encoded. The file is not screwed up we are just not reading it right. `Get-Content -path $path -Encoding Unicode` maybe?

Comment: thank you for all your help I feel like a total noob! When I add in the -Encoding Unicode it displays the csv in the PowerShell window but the resulting csv file it creates is empty. At the moment I have Get-Content -path $path -Encoding Unicode
ForEach-Object {$_ -replace "`t",";" } |
Set-Content  -path $outPath

Comment: Ignore me. I missed out the | after setting the encoding after I spotted that it has worked :) thank you again for your help

Comment: Set-content would have the same issue if you need your output to be in unicode: ``Get-Content -path $path -Encoding Unicode ForEach-Object {$_ -replace "`t",";" } | Set-Content -path $outPath -Encoding Unicode``

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function I used to replace strings in text files like you're doing. This is assuming there's no tabs inside the text file other than those that are delimiting the columns. I'm assuming there's not. You can use it like this:

```
Find-InTextFile -FilePath C:\MyFile.csv -Find "`t" -Replace ';'

function Find-InTextFile
{
    <#
    .SYNOPSIS
        Performs a find (or replace) on a string in a text file or files.
    .EXAMPLE
        PS> Find-InTextFile -FilePath 'C:\MyFile.txt' -Find 'water' -Replace 'wine'

        Replaces all instances of the string 'water' into the string 'wine' in
        'C:\MyFile.txt'.
    .EXAMPLE
        PS> Find-InTextFile -FilePath 'C:\MyFile.txt' -Find 'water'

        Finds all instances of the string 'water' in the file 'C:\MyFile.txt'.
    .PARAMETER FilePath
        The file path of the text file you'd like to perform a find/replace on.
    .PARAMETER Find
        The string you'd like to replace.
    .PARAMETER Replace
        The string you'd like to replace your 'Find' string with.
    .PARAMETER UseRegex
        Use this switch parameter if you're finding strings using regex else the Find string will
        be escaped from regex characters
    .PARAMETER NewFilePath
        If a new file with the replaced the string needs to be created instead of replacing
        the contents of the existing file use this param to create a new file.
    .PARAMETER Force
        If the NewFilePath param is used using this param will overwrite any file that
        exists in NewFilePath.
    #>
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = 'NewFile')]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [ValidateScript({ Test-Path -Path $_ -PathType 'Leaf' })]
        [string[]]$FilePath,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [string]$Find,

        [Parameter()]
        [string]$Replace,

        [Parameter()]
        [switch]$UseRegex,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'NewFile')]
        [ValidateScript({ Test-Path -Path ($_ | Split-Path -Parent) -PathType 'Container' })]
        [string]$NewFilePath,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'NewFile')]
        [switch]$Force
    )
    begin
    {
        if (!$UseRegex.IsPresent)
        {
            $Find = [regex]::Escape($Find)
        }
    }
    process
    {
        try
        {
            foreach ($File in $FilePath)
            {
                if ($Replace)
                {
                    if ($NewFilePath)
                    {
                        if ((Test-Path -Path $NewFilePath -PathType 'Leaf') -and $Force.IsPresent)
                        {
                            Remove-Item -Path $NewFilePath -Force
                            (Get-Content $File) -replace $Find, $Replace | Add-Content -Path $NewFilePath -Force
                        }
                        elseif ((Test-Path -Path $NewFilePath -PathType 'Leaf') -and !$Force.IsPresent)
                        {
                            Write-Warning "The file at '$NewFilePath' already exists and the -Force param was not used"
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            (Get-Content $File) -replace $Find, $Replace | Add-Content -Path $NewFilePath -Force
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        (Get-Content $File) -replace $Find, $Replace | Add-Content -Path "$File.tmp" -Force
                        Remove-Item -Path $File
                        Rename-Item -Path "$File.tmp" -NewName $File
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Select-String -Path $File -Pattern $Find
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            Write-Error -Message $_.Exception.Message
        }
    }
}
```